# Error in swift When I delete a row it do it but crash

Tags: swift, crash

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
    let object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    object.delete()
```

> When I decided to use delete it worked but the app crashes

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
} else if editingStyle == .Insert {
// Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}
}
```

> this is the error *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720
>   2016-01-19 00:07:30.451 Registro1[21154:852511] ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it seems like you are not deleting the corresponding object from the datasource array, `noteObjects`. Hence, there is  mismatch between the datasource array count and TableView internal count after you call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

Try adding the below line, before calling `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

```
self.noteObjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Is it a sectioned tableview ? If you are removing a row that is the last item in a section you need to remove the whole section. Otherwise, it throws this exception.

Comment: I tried to use your code but it throws errors and tried the Sohil R. Memon solution it delete the hole object but the app crashes

Comment: Include code snippets to show how you are populating table view. It will help to understand more about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting any row from `UITableView`, you need to call `reloadData()` or you can tie that method under `beginUpdates` or `endUpdates()`.

> Example:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now I have this error *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720
2016-01-19 10:21:33.980 Registro1[21521:899913] ***